# How to resize web-page header without getting blurry at different sizes?

Tags: image, photoshop

i have an PSD file for a website header and it's (960x152) pixel i want to resize it so it appear like it was made at this size for example resize from 960x125 to:

1. 851 X 350  pixels
2. 2120 X 1192  pixels (16:9 ratio)

3.270  X  270  pixels

4.1545 X  423  pixels

thanks in advance

Comment: you're wanting to resize this using Photoshop specifically or through the website using CSS?  And there are things to mitigate the blurring slightly at higher resolutions but you're going to get blur no matter what.  Depending what this image is you might be better off making it seamless and repeating it.  Can you post a link to it?

Comment: no css use just Photoshop or if you have any other suggestion it will be good, this images to be put in different media site like linkedin and google+

Comment: Well taking any image from a skinny rectangle to a straight square is going to be awkward, and even worse if it's being upscaled.  I use GIMP and like the Enhance > Unsharp Mask filter for this particular situation.  I'm sure PS has it too, try that out once you scale it up and let us know how it comes out.

Comment: when i scale it up or down as you said it's going to be awkward, i want just to make my image fit to facebook cover, google+ and so on, the problem is each site has different pixel size so can i find any tool to solve this problem to me ?

Answer (score 0):

[This will be your best bet](http://www.ononesoftware.com/products/perfect-resize/) (I'm actually gonna try it too).  -  OnOne Perfect Resize 7.5

There's a free trial to test out.  After [reading](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CF4QFjAE&url=http://chrislema.com/how-to-resize-images-to-make-them-larger-without-losing-quality/&ei=RFxrUovPMdKikQf08oCIAQ&usg=AFQjCNGT7CXs_9wg0voROGOXsbgqGzRQ3A&sig2=XY8SuH-WifBIEGXoGQ27jw&bvm=bv.55123115,d.eW0) a [few reviews](http://blog.kenkaminesky.com/onone-perfect-resize-software-review/) it seems to be legit.

Comment: figures...sorry man i'll keep lookin around.  i need it for my own stuff too anyway lol

Comment: i solved it but with some work and i think it's the best result i can get, and thank you for helping me @Deryck

Answer (score 0):

This is the best result i can get after trying many solution, but it takes some work and effective in PSD files that don't have a lot of layers:

1. open the PSD file and make sure all the layers that you want all visible.
2. convert each layer into a smart object.
3. create new PSD file with the new dimensions that you want.
4. use grid and guidelines to make your work more easy.
5. transform each layer (object) to get the desired lock inside the PSD file.

i hope this can help.